# Preferred method for creating JPA datasource in Tomee

Tags: datasource, jpa-2.0, jndi, apache-tomee

As a newbie to Tomee 2.0, I was trying to research how to create a datasource in which can be injected into an ejb as a @persistencecontext.  It is sometimes hard to figure out what solutions are obsolete and do not really work any more; but I found suggestions using server.xml (definitely obsolete; except maybe with globalNamingResources) context.xml, tomee.xml, resources.xml, openejb.xml.  Does anyone have an example of defining a datasource that will then be automatically looked up using the persistence.xml jta-data-source.  If it makes a difference, I will be using container managed beans using JPA and a sql server XAdatasource.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have a look at the official Tomee Website which gives you some code examples that work out of the box. E.g., you can inject an instance of `EntityManager` via `@PersistenceContext` like this:

[Injection of an EntityManager](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/injection-of-entitymanager/README.html)

If you want to use a `DataSource` directly you should have a look at this example:

[Injection of a DataSource](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/injection-of-datasource/README.html)

> ```
> /**
>  * The field name "movieDatabase" matches the DataSource we
>  * configure in the TestCase via :
>  * p.put("movieDatabase", "new://Resource?type=DataSource");
>  * <p/>
>  * This would also match an equivalent delcaration in an openejb.xml:
>  * <Resource id="movieDatabase" type="DataSource"/>
>  * <p/>
>  * If you'd like the freedom to change the field name without
>  * impact on your configuration you can set the "name" attribute
>  * of the @Resource annotation to "movieDatabase" instead.
>  */
> @Resource
> private DataSource movieDatabase;
> ```

In this example - as you can see above - `openejb.xml` is referenced.

Hope it helps to spot the missing parts. (comments welcome)